# Having trouble using Pthread mutex to synchronize multiple threads

Tags: c, synchronization, locking, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to set up a program in which some number of threads (as specified at the command line) will be spawned. Each thread will repeatedly request some number of the finite number (in this case 5) of resources available. It will then sleep for as many seconds as the number of resources it received (ie: 3 resources granted -> 3 seconds sleeping), then return the resources to the pool.

I have set up my `increaseCount()` and `decreaseCount()` procedures with the intention of requiring a thread to ackquire a pthread mutex called `lock` before it can access the global variable `available resources`, which keeps track of how many resources from the pool of 5 are available.

Currently, my program makes one or a couple requests which are granted, but runs out of resources quickly and rifles on by, printing thousands of my `insufficient resources...` messages.

Can anyone see an obvious flaw in the logic behind my procedure?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void * threadProcedure(void * i){
int a = *((int *) i);
do{
    /* Generate a random number [1, MAX_RESOURCES] of resources to request */
    time_t t;
    srand((int)time(&t) % a);
    int requestNum = (rand() % MAX_RESOURCES) + 1;

    /* Request that many resources */
    resourcesReceived = decreaseCount(requestNum);
    /* Sleep for a time (in seconds) proportional to the number of resources requested */
    sleep(resourcesReceived);
    /* Return the resources */
    if(resourcesReceived > 0){ increaseCount(resourcesReceived); }

}while(1);
}//end threadProcedure
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int decreaseCount(int x){
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //Acquire the lock

//If the requested number of resources aren't available
if(x > availableResources){
    printf("Insufficient resources. Requested: %d Available: %d\n", x, availableResources);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Reset the lock
    return 0; //Return without allocating any resources
}

//If the requested resources ARE available
else{
    printf("Allocating. %d resources. ", x);
    availableResources -= x; //Allocate resources
    printf("availableResources: %d\n", availableResources);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Free (unlock) the lock
    return x;
}
}//end decreaseCount
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int increaseCount(int x){
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //Acquire the lock

availableResources += x; //Update the number of available resources
printf("availableResources: %d\n\n", availableResources);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Free (unlock) the lock

return 0;
}//end increaseCount
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my attempt at using `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal` to alleviate the problem: (Output still prints incredibly fast/non-stop)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int decreaseCount(int x){
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //Acquire the lock

pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);

//If the requested number of resources aren't available
if(x > availableResources){
    printf("Requested: %d, Available: %d. Denied.\n", x, availableResources);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Reset the lock
    return 0; //Return without allocating any resources
}

//If the requested resources ARE available
else{
    printf("Requested: %d, Available: %d. Allocated.\t",x, availableResources);
    availableResources -= x; //Allocate resources
    printf("availableResources: %d\n", availableResources);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Free (unlock) the lock
    return x;
}
}//end decreaseCount
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int increaseCount(int x){
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //Acquire the lock

pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

availableResources += x; //Update the number of available resources
printf("%d resources returned. availableResources: %d\n\n", x, availableResources);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //Free (unlock) the lock

return 0;
}//end increaseCount
```

My output looks like this:

```
Requested: 2, Available: 5. Allocated.  availableResources: 3
Requested: 2, Available: 3. Allocated.  availableResources: 1
Requested: 1, Available: 1. Allocated.  availableResources: 0
Requested: 2, Available: 0. Denied.
Requested: 2, Available: 0. Denied.
2 resources returned. availableResources: 2

2 resources returned. availableResources: 4

1 resources returned. availableResources: 5

Requested: 2, Available: 5. Allocated.  availableResources: 3
Requested: 2, Available: 3. Allocated.  availableResources: 1
Requested: 2, Available: 1. Denied.
```

Comment: Once all the resources are grabbed then no one can get them until they are released. So depending on how many threads you spawn it is likely that most of the time the threads are spinning waiting for resources to become free. The use of mutexes protects the critical section but it does not provide adequate synchronisation. That is, you ideally should have synchronisation that blocks each thread if there is no resources available. The usual way to do this is with conditional variables. See [pthread_cond_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) and the other `pthread_cond` functions.

Comment: As an example, consider creating 10 threads and that there are 100 resources. Consider what happens if the first thread gets all 100 resources. It sleeps for 100 seconds. Meanwhile the other 9 threads are spinning continuously full throttle for 100 seconds printing "Insufficient resources....".

Comment: @kaylum Thank you. After looking at that documentation, I am still a bit confused on how to use `pthread_cond_wait`. I think I should make the thread acquire `lock` like before, but now, instead of returning as soon as I know (and have printed) that the requested resources are not available, the thread should wait for the number of seconds equal to the number of resources it requested. However, I am not sure how I would implement that.

Comment: You should not sleep explicitly. `pthread_cond_wait` will sleep for you. Instead, the `increaseCount` function should call `pthread_cond_signal` if `availableResources` is 0 to wake up one of the threads that may be blocked. If that is not clear let me know and I'll try to write an example (but it may be a few hours before I can do that). But I do encourage you to give it a go. Maybe start with a simpler test program if you need to understand how `pthread_cond` works.

Comment: @kaylum Working on it now. Thank you so much for your willingness to help.